# In Flutter, how can I align an arbitrary point in one widget with an arbitrary point in another?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm developing an app in Flutter that takes a snapshot of a Google Map (so I have the image available to display offline) and displays a location icon on top of it.

Along with the map snapshot, I capture the latitude and longitude of the four corners of the map. So with a current GPS reading, I can figure the relative location in the map to display the location icon.

The problem is that I want the pointy part of the icon to be positioned at the GPS location. That means the mid-point of the bottom edge of the icon.

Currently, I'm using a Stack with the map image as the first layer and the icon stacked on top, positioned using the FractionalOffset widget:

```
  // Calculate the relative location of the icon over the map
  // by finding the ratio of our current location in the
  // map
  double locationMarkerLeft = (_currentLocation.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude) /
        (bounds.northeast.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude);
  double locationMarkerTop = (_currentLocation.latitude - bounds.northeast.latitude) /
        (bounds.southwest.latitude - bounds.northeast.latitude);

  return Stack(children: <Widget>[
    Image.memory(_mapImage),
    Align(child: Icon(Icons.location_on),
        alignment: FractionalOffset(locationMarkerLeft, locationMarkerTop)
    )
  ]);
```

My understanding is that FractionalOffset applies the same relative offset to the parent and the child. So while this positions the icon approximately, it is not exact.

So, how can I position the mid-point of the bottom edge of the icon at a specific point atop the image of the map?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use the size of the icon (which is 24 by default) for you calculation.

Here is your code modified:

```
    // Calculate the relative location of the icon over the map
    // by finding the ratio of our current location in the
    // map
    double locationMarkerLeft = (_currentLocation.longitude - 24/2 - bounds.southwest.longitude) /
        (bounds.northeast.longitude - bounds.southwest.longitude);
    double locationMarkerTop = (_currentLocation.latitude - bounds.northeast.latitude) /
        (bounds.southwest.latitude - bounds.northeast.latitude);

    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Image.memory(_mapImage),
      Align(child: Icon(Icons.location_on),
          alignment: FractionalOffset(locationMarkerLeft, locationMarkerTop)
      )
    ]);
```

Comment: But that 24/2 is getting divided by the number of degrees of longitude wide the map is. The result is meaningless.

If I could get the size of the widget, I could calculate something useful. But you can't get that while building the widget.